# Distribution and convergence of the r.vs.: $X_n= \frac{ \lfloor nX \rfloor}{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$X$ is an absolutely continous random variable, with a continous density function, and:

$$X_n= \frac{ \lfloor nX \rfloor}{n}$$

What is the distribution of $X_n$, and what can we say about its convergence?

I tried to calculate the distribution like this:

$$\begin{align*}P(X_n =k)&=P\left(\frac{ \lfloor nX \rfloor}{n}=k\right)=P\left(nk\leq nX <n(k+1)\right)=\int_k^{k+1} f_X\;dx\\&=F_X(k+1)-F_X(k)\end{align*}$$

I am not sure what I did was right, please help!

Comment: Yes, it seems fine.

Comment: The formula is wrong. Try rather, for every integer $i$, $$P(X_n=i/n)=F_X((i+1)/n)-F_X(i/n).$$

Comment: @Did Does this mean that $X_n$ converges to 0 and not to $X$?

Comment: No, since $P(X_n\leqslant x)\to F_X(x)$ for every $x$.